# Error on changing the resolution of a vnc session in linux on the fly

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver, xrandr

I connect to my workstation which is a  linux box(Red Hat Linux) from a my laptop(windows 7 machine) through RealVNC . When I am work I use a docking station and the resolution of it is quite high and my laptop has lower resolution . So when I switch between my monitor and my laptop I need to restart vncserver everytime with the proper geometry. Searching on the internet I landed [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083668/1527084) on stackoverflow.com which describes way to assign a different geometry on the fly .   The key here is the `randr` argument while starting vncserver . So the first thing I did is to ensure that Xrandr is installed on my linux box :

```
which xrandr
```

This gives the following output :

```
 /usr/bin/xrandr
```

Next I tried running the server with the command :

```
 vncserver -geometry 1600x1200 -randr 1600x1200,1440x900,1024x768
```

But the server didn't start . Next I started the server with only the `-geometry` argument  and **without** the `randr` argument as given in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839759/152708) .

Next from the terminal I issued the xrandr command and got the following error :

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
```

What does the above error mean  and what  am I missing here ?

Comment: Are you using RedHat or Linux native vncserver? I've noticed that vncserver doesn't support RANDR. I'm trying to see if there is a way to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu server, it wasn't working either with the `-randr` parameter, but it works great by using several times the `-geometry` parameter. Give it a try.

So you would enter:

```
vncserver -geometry 1600x1200 -geometry 1440x900 -geometry 1024x768
```

And after, you use the `xrandr` command to change the resolution.

Comment: YES! Finally! This works w/ Ubuntu 14.04 + vnc4server 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. This gave me the same error:

```
vncconfig -set RandR="1855x1055"
```

SOLUTION:

1. open VNC server 'Options' dialog
2. go to 'Expert' tab
3. find the 'RandR' parameter and set the value as needed!

[See Options screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfMHF.png)

After clicking 'Apply' you'll be able to resize screen with

```
xrandr -s 1855x1055
```

That worked for me, I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, off the top of my head, that your version of VNC doesn't support `RANDR`.  Are you sure it's supported?

Comment: exactly. tightvnc doesn't support randr. tigervnc does. replacing fixed this. thanks!